# Why can we use a new class as type of parent class in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, locking, actor, f-bounded-polymorphism

In the simplified implementation of Actor in the RedBook, they use node-based MPSC node based queue for Actor. They define the node by this line of code:

```scala
private class Node[A](var a: A = null.asInstanceOf[A]) extends AtomicReference[Node[A]]
```

But how can we use `Node[A]` as the type parameter of `AtomicReference` because we do not have `class Node[A]` yet? Is it a way of declaring recursive type in Scala?

Comment: It is called **F-Bounded Polymorphism**, you can search more about the topic. It is a somewhat common technique in OOP languages, like Java _(Enums in Java use it)_. And you can use it, because the type is already defined, the class not, but the type yes. Types & classes are not the same. - PS: In Scala is not that common to use it, because the language lacks proper support for a correct encoding, and mainly because **Typeclasses** are a better alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are allowed to use recursion in class/trait definition:

```scala
abstract class Example[A] extends (A => Example[A])

def example(prefix: String): Example[String] = new Example[String] {
  def apply(s: String): Example[String] = {
    val t = prefix + s
    println(t)
    example(t)
  }
}

example("1")("2")("3") 
//12
//123
```

If you have `X extends F[X]` then you ended up with something known to C++ developers as [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and in type theory in general as [F-bounded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).

You can find it even in Java because each `enum X` is underneath `abstract class X extends Enum[X]`.

Comment: So it means ```Node[A]``` will have type ```AtomicReference[AtomicReference[...Node[A]]```.

Comment: `Node[A]` _is_ the type `Node[A]` which is a subtype of `AtomicReference[Node[A]]`. `AtomicReference` is not recursive on itself.